# Passing MySql DB data between forms

Tags: c#, mysql, database, forms

Alright so I made two forms form1 and form2. Form1s code looks like this..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ACIDeXe_DBTEST
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void nsButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SHA1HASH();
            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=encrypti_dropem;password=PASSWORD";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from encrypti_dropem.users where username='" + this.username_txt.Text + "' and password='" + password_txt.Text + "' ;", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                Stresser hub = new Stresser(username_txt.Text);
                this.Hide();
                hub.Show();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database error code: 1");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
            myConn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
    public void SHA1HASH()
    {
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        string rpassword = BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(password_txt.Text)));
        string lpassword = rpassword.Replace("-", "");
        password_txt.Text = String.Empty;
        password_txt.Text = lpassword;
    }
}
}
```

So it logins, and passes the username to form2 (at the moment). I tried using this code to grab the rank of the user and passing that directly but I can't figure it out..

```
string myConnection =  datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=encrypti_dropem;password=PASSWORD";       
            MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from         encrypti_dropem.users where username='" + label9.Text + "';", myCon);
            MySqlDataReader reader2;
            myCon.Open();
            reader2 = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                string rankid = reader2.GetString("rank");              
            }
            myCon.Close();
```

I feel as if I missed alot when trying to learn c#, like passing data between forms or something? Anyone wanna try to help me go in the right direction.

TLDR; Need to be able to use the string rankid (obtained on form1) in form2 ALL THROUGHOUT the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sesseion varible to pass data to other form.

```
string myConnection =  datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=encrypti_dropem;password=PASSWORD";       
        MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from         encrypti_dropem.users where username='" + label9.Text + "';", myCon);
        MySqlDataReader reader2;
        myCon.Open();
        reader2 = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader2.Read())
        {
            Session["rankid"] = reader2.GetString("rank");              
        }
        myCon.Close();
```

and on other page You can below code to access rankid:

```
      string strRank  =  Convert.ToString(Session["rankid"]);
```

And

For Window Form U can use below code on Form1 where u open form2:

```
    var frm2 = new Form2(reader2.GetString("rank"););
    frm2.Show();
```

and On Form2 use below code:

```
 public Form2(string s)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = s;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I keep getting Session doesn't exist in current context. I tried looking for solution can't find any.. any personal experience with this?

Comment: Hi U can use code for Window form as i have mentioned in my ans. Session is used for web application. plz use below code:  var frm2 = new Form2(reader2.GetString("rank"););
    frm2.Show();